# iOS: design gets weird on click on viewController

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have a table that contains collection views in each of its cells. On click on collection cell, the table cell get expanded and shows a storyBoard (highlight in pictures image 1). But this storyBoard has a strange behavior. Normally on click on buttons it must navigate to different controller but when click on gray space it gets messy as you see in image 2

[image: image of the app execution] (image 1 and image 2)

[image: image of storyBoard controllers in inspector]

**Solution**

The UITableView is applying the cell selection styling when the user taps into an area of the UICollectionView that passes thru to the UITableViewCell. 
so adding `cell.selectionStyle = .none` to `cellForRowAt indexPath` solved the problem .
thanks to @myuiviews

Comment: Can you show your didSelectMethod

Comment: Im not using `didSelectMethod` on `tableCell`, but I am using `didSelectMethod` on `collectionViewCell`, witch is not relavent to the issue

Comment: The UITableView may be applying the cell selection styling when the user taps into an area of the UICollectionView that passes thru to the UITableViewCell.  Seems like an odd combination of using UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell.  I'd recommend using UIStackView to accomplish this type of layout perhaps.

Comment: Thanks @myuiviews saved me hours, Im surprised how u thought about that!!. I added `cell.selectionStyle = .none` to `cellForRowAt indexPath`. Im curios about the ÙIStackView` thing, I searched a lot before I went with the collection inside tableCell, but why do you recommend it ?